# How to download pdf files in python?

Tags: python

I need to download something like

```
str = 'http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9A00EEDE1431E13BBC4850DFBF66838A649FDE'
url = urllib2.urlopen(str)
file = open('test.pdf', 'w')
file.write(url.read())
file.close()
```

It just creates a wrong pdf.

how do I write that into file?

Comment: It is unclear: do you want to *open* it (a difficult thing to do), or do you want to *download* it? In the case of the latter, `urllib` might work.

Comment: [`urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

Comment: we are here to help you with problems with your code, not to create code for you.

Comment: Here is a similar question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751490/322909

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening pdf urls with pyPdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751197/opening-pdf-urls-with-pypdf)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`pattern`](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern) module, which is built on top of `urllib2` and has a higher level of abstraction.

```
from pattern.web import URL

url = URL('http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9A00EEDE1431E13BBC4850DFBF66838A649FDE')
f = open('nytimes.pdf', 'wb')
f.write(url.download(cached=False))
f.close()
```