# parsing a remote pdf file with Python3 & PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, decode, pypdf

I need to parse a remote pdf file. With PyPDF2, it can be done by `PdfReader(f)`, where f=urllib.request.urlopen("some-url").read() . f cannot be used by the PdfReader, and it seems that f has to be decoded. What argument should be used in decode(), or some other method has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen("some-url").read()
```

Add these lines after above line:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

f = StringIO(f)
```

and then read  using PdfReader as:

```
reader = PdfReader(f)
```

Also, refer: [Opening pdf urls with pyPdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751197/opening-pdf-urls-with-pypdf)

Comment: pypdf is spelled all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to decode using [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```
import urllib, PyPDF2
from io import BytesIO
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://mypdf.pdf").read()
pdf_bytes = BytesIO(f)
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf